# Moving ModalPopup Outside the IFrame. Possible?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, modalpopupextender

I have an iframe inside my main page. There is a modalpopup inside the iframe page. So when the modalpopup is shown, the parent of the modalpopup is the iframe body and the main page parent body. Thus the overlay only covers the iframe and not the entire page.

I tried moving the modalpopup from the iframe to the parent windows body element (or any other element inside the parents body) using jQuery. I am getting an invalid argument error.

How do I show a modalpopup from an page inside iframe and it should cover the entire document, parent document as well?

**Update:**

Since few users are interested in achieving the same behavior .. here is the workaround

The best workaround that I would suggest would be to have the modalpopup in the main page .. and then invoke it from the iframe .. say something like this ..

```
/* function in the main(parent) page */
var _onMyModalPopupHide = null;
function pageLoad(){
    // would be called by ScriptManager when page loads
    // add the callback that will be called when the modalpopup is closed
    $find('MyModalPopupBehaviorID').add_hidden(onMyModalPopupHide);
}
// will be invoked from the iframe to show the popup
function ShowMyModalPopup(callback) {
    _onMyModalPopupHide = callback;
    $find('MyModalPopupBehaviorID').show();
}
/* this function would be called when the modal popup is closed */
function onMyModalPopupHide(){
    if (typeof(_onMyModalPopupHide) === "function") {
        // fire the callback function
        _onMyModalPopupHide.call(this);
    }
}

/* functions in the page loaded in the iframe */
function ShowPopup(){
    if(typeof(window.parent.ShowMyModalPopup) === "function") {
        window.parent.ShowMyModalPopup.apply(this, [OnPopupClosed]);
    }
}
// will be invoked from the parent page .. after the popup is closed
function OnPopupClosed(){
    // do something after the modal popup is closed
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If you're going to include a solution, please post it as an answer rather than an update to the question. It's less confusing that way and helps others focus on the question that might have a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the iframe simply for scrollable content you might consider a styled div with **overflow: auto** or **scroll**, instead.

A set up such as this makes it easier to modify the appearance of the entire page since you're not working with multiple documents that each essentially have their own window space inside the page. You can bypass some of the cross-frame communication and it may be easier to keep the information in sync if you need to do that.

This may not be suitable for all situations and may require ajax (or modifying the dom with javascript) to change the div contents instead of just loading a different document in the iframe.  Also, some older mobile browsers such as Android Froyo builds don't handle scrollable divs well.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question in your update.  The modal dialog needs to live on the parent page and invoked from the iframe.  Your only other option is to use a scrolling div instead of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible the way you are asking. Think of it this way: an iframe is a seperate window. You cannot (for the time being) move a div in one webpage into another.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by writing a small code for jQuery see below maybe this can help :

**NOTE: Make sure you are doing on same domain**

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="popup">Show Popup</button>
<br />
<br />
<iframe src="your url" style="width: 100%; height:400px;"></iframe>
```

**JS:**

```
// Author : Adeel Rizvi
// It's just a attempt to get the desire element inside the iframe show outside from iframe as a model popup window.

// As i don't have the access inside the iframe for now, so I'll grab the desire element from parent window.

(function () {
    $.fn.toPopup = function () {
        return this.each(function () {

            // Create dynamic div and set its properties
            var popUpDiv = $("<div />", {
                class: "com_popup",
                width: "100%",
                height: window.innerHeight
            });

            // append all the html into newly created div
            $(this).appendTo(popUpDiv);

            // check if we are in iframe or not
            if ($('body', window.parent.document).length !== 0) {

                // get iframe parent window body element
                var parentBody = $('body', window.parent.document);

                // set height according to parent window body
                popUpDiv.css("height", parentBody.height());

                // add newly created div into parent window body
                popUpDiv.appendTo(parentBody);

            } else {

                // if not inside iframe then add to current window body
                popUpDiv.appendTo($('body'));
            }

        });
    }
})();

$(function(){
 $("#popup").click(function () {

    // find element inside the iframe
    var bodyDiv = $('iframe').contents().find('YourSelector');


    if (bodyDiv.length !== 0) {

        // Show
        $(bodyDiv).toPopup();

    } else {
        alert('Sorry!, no element found');
    }

 });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.com_popup {
    background-color: Blue;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```