# How to open modal of iframe always in center of main screen irrespective of iframe height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe

I'm using iframe in my site. There are lots of question list each question has button add comment and on this button click modal opens. I want to set this modal always in center of screen irrespective of height of iframe. I have option in modal property like position top center bottom but is should be open near clicked add comment button instead of iframe of top.

Note: I have access of iframe we can use postmessage if it has solution

[image]

check above image modal opened on top of iframe instead of visible screen or near add comment button

how to adjust its position to near clicked add comment button?

[image]

it showing on top of iframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving ModalPopup Outside the IFrame. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295621/moving-modalpopup-outside-the-iframe-possible) (specifically the modal cannot get outside of its iFrame, but one of the answers uses the parent page to get the popup content from the iFrame to display it. It can be adapter with postMessage)

Comment: I guess no @Kaddath

Comment: I'm using reactjs on both platform

Comment: Have you actually read the answers? Anyway you should add details to your question, example of code, and limit to one question only

Comment: yes none of them useable answer, I have iframe on different domain but I have access of it. we can communicate through postmessage

Comment: I'm just trying to help, but I won't go through every possible solution in a tutorial. You have different solutions, you must choose one. Good luck